# How to SELECT ALL columns but COUNT of one Column in SQL query

Tags: sql, count

I want to select all the columns of a table, plus total employee count in a department. This is to create sample data:

```
DECLARE @CompanyTable TABLE
     (
    [EMPID] int NOT NULL,
    [FNAME] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [LNAME] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [COUNTRY] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CITY] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DEPARTMENT] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL)
insert into @CompanyTable VALUES (1,  'ANGEL', 'HILL','US','SF','HR')
,(2,  'ANGEL', 'HILL','US','TAMPA','HR')
,(3,  'VICTOR', 'FENCL','US','NEW YORK','TECH')
,(4,  'ANNA', 'NEAL','US','CLEVELAND','HR')
,(5,  'CARRIE', 'NICHOLS','CANADA','EDMINTON','HR')
,(6,  'CATHY', 'HILL','CANADA','TORONTO','PAYROLL')
,(7,  'LINDA', 'REED','CANADA','TORONTO','HR')
,(8,  'ANNA', 'NEAL','UK','LONDON','HR')
,(9,  'JAIME', 'RODRIGUEZ','UK','LONDON','TECH')
,(10,  'DANA', 'NICHOLS','US','SF','HR')
,(11,  'ANGEL', 'WEBB','US','SF','PAYROLL')
,(12,  'CATHY', 'JORDAN','US','SF','TECH');
```

I can do this, without selecting all columns and grouping on one

```
SELECT 
     [DEPARTMENT],  count([EMPID]) [EMP_COUNT]
  FROM @CompanyTable
  GROUP by [DEPARTMENT]
```

But how to select all columns, and total EMP_COUNT per DEPARTMENT, something like

```
EMPID   FNAME   LNAME   COUNTRY CITY        DEPARTMENT    EMP_COUNT
1       ANGEL   HILL    US      SF          HR              7
2       ANGEL   HILL    US      TAMPA       HR              7
3       VICTOR  FENCL   US      NEW YORK    TECH            3
4       ANNA    NEAL    US      CLEVELAND   HR              7
5       CARRIE  NICHOLS CANADA  EDMINTON    HR              7
6       CATHY   HILL    CANADA  TORONTO     PAYROLL         2
7       LINDA   REED    CANADA  TORONTO     HR              7
8       ANNA    NEAL    UK      LONDON      HR              7
9       JAIME   TIPTON  UK      LONDON      TECH            3
10      DANA    NICHOLS US      SF          HR              7
11      ANGEL   WEBB    US      SF          PAYROLL         2
12      CATHY   JORDAN  US      SF          TECH            3
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it for `SQL Server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `windows function`, partitioning by department. This works in many DBMS. Please tag your DBMS if this does not work for you.

```
SELECT 
     *, 
     count(empid) over (partition by department) as emp_count
  FROM @CompanyTable
 order by empid
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jjr5IIKy)